# How to show the orbit space $\mathbb S^n/\mathbb Z_2$ is $\mathbb RP^n$?

Tags: manifolds, group-actions

How to show the orbit space $\mathbb S^n/\mathbb Z_2$ is $\mathbb RP^n$? Here $\mathbb Z_2=\{0, 1\}$ is the additive group and the group action considered induces the aplications $\psi_0=Id$ and $\psi_1=-Id$.

Comment: I think you mean $Z_2$.

Comment: Yeah that's right =D

Answer (score 2):

The map $S^n\to \mathbb P^n(\mathbb R): s\mapsto \mathbb R\cdot s$ is continuous and induces a bijection $S^n/\mu_2\to \mathbb P^n(\mathbb R)$ ($\mu_2=\{Id, -Id\}$).
That bijection is continuous by the [universal property of quotient topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space#Properties) and is a homeomorphism, like all [continuous bijections from compact spaces to Hausdorff spaces](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism).
This proof can be adapted to show that the above homeomorphism is also a diffeomorphism of smooth  manifolds.

Comment: but I still have a doubt.. when it says the orbit space of $\mathbb S^n/\mathbb Z_2$ is $\mathbb RP^n$ it means $\mathbb S^n/\mathbb Z_2=\mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ as sets or that there is a homeomorphism between this two spaces?

Comment: In my interpretation it is a homeomorphism. I have used implicitly the definition of $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb R)$ as the set of lines through the origin of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$

Comment: I think it is a homeomorphism too..